# getting a run time error in dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c++, linked-list, runtime-error, dynamic-memory-allocation

The program is supposed to allocate memory as an operating system would do.

This is the main function

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[]){
  string command;

 if(argc==2)
      command = argv[1];

 else cout<<"Not enough commands"<<endl;

 if (command.compare("best"))
     cout<<"Using best fit algorithm"<<endl;

 if (command.compare("worst"))
     cout<<"Using worst fit algorithm"<<endl;

 cout<<"\t1.Add Program\n";
 cout<<"\t2.Kill Program\n";
 cout<<"\t3.Fragmentation\n";
 cout<<"\t4.Print Memory\n";
 cout<<"\t5.Exit\n";

 LinkedList Memory;
 Memory.createMemory();

 int choice;
 cin>>choice;
 cout<<"choice - "<<choice<<endl;

 if  (choice==1){
     string programName;
     cin>>programName;
     cout<<"Program name - "<<programName<<endl;
     int si;
     cin>>si;
     cout<<"Program size (KB) - "<<si<<endl;
     Memory.addProgram(si, programName);
 }
 if  (choice==2){
     string programName;
     cin>>programName;
     cout<<"Program name - "<<programName<<endl;
     Memory.killProgram(programName);
 }
 if  (choice==4){
     Memory.print();
 }
 if  (choice==5){
     return 1;
}
return 0;
}
```

And this is the linkedlist class with its functions

```
 class LinkedList{
 private:
    struct node{
      string name;
      node *next;
    };
    typedef struct node * nodePointer;
    nodePointer head;
 public:
    void createMemory();
    void addProgram(int val, string s);
    void killProgram(string s1);
    void print();
    void fragmentation();
 LinkedList(){head=NULL;}
 };
 void LinkedList::createMemory(){
 int i=0;
 node* temp=head;
 while(i<32){
    temp->name="Free";
    temp=temp->next;
    i++;
 }
 };

 void LinkedList::addProgram(int val, string s){
 int i=0;
 node* temp=head;
 while(temp->name!="Free")
    temp=temp->next;
 while(temp->name=="Free"){
    while (i<val){
      temp->name=s;
      temp=temp->next;
      i++;
 }
 }
 };

 void LinkedList::killProgram(string s){
    node* temp=head;
 while(temp->name!=s)
    temp=temp->next;
 while(temp->name==s)
    temp->name="Free";
 };

 void LinkedList::print(){
 node*temp=head;
 int i=0;
 while(i<32){
  cout<<temp->name<<"\t";
  temp=temp->next;
    if ((i+1)%8==0){
       cout<<endl;
 }
 i++;
 }
 };
```

Whenever I call one of the class functions I get a run time error and i don't understand why

Answer (score 1):

You have the member `LinkedList::head` which you initialize to a null pointer.

Then in `LinkedList::createMemory` you do `node* temp=head` which makes `temp` a null pointer.

Lastly in the loop in `createMemory` you do `temp->name="Free"` which dereferences the null pointer and lead to *undefined behavior* and a very likely crash.

If you want 32 preallocated nodes in the list, then you should actually *allocate* memory for those nodes.

Comment: @Matteo How about `head = temp = new node`?

Comment: So declaring temp as pointer to node and then writing      head = temp =new node

Answer (score 0):

```
LinkedList memory;
memory.createMemory();
```

This code is probably the source of your error. memory doesn't have any value yet, so when you try to access the function "createMemory" inside memory, you get a null pointer error.
In general, try to give more information when you ask a question. This question would be much clearer if you added what error you were getting, what line it occurs at, the error message, or similar things.

Comment: It doesn't give me a specific error it just says program2.exe stopped working and then it crashes

Comment: That's unusual. What are you using to execute the code?

Comment: I'd expect that to print the error message, but I don't have any experience with code blocks, so I'll defer to someone more knowledgeable.

Answer (score 0):

When you invoke `Memory.createMemory();`, this program will crash. 
Because you didn't allocate memory for `temp` in the function `createMemory()`, `temp` points to NULL, so `temp->name="Free";`will crash your program. You should use `new` to allocate memory for `temp`. You should try [this site](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/) to help you.

BTW, the way you treat the command parameter is not appropriate, what if the user input more than 2 parameters, and you tell the user there is `Not enough commands`.

```
if(argc==2)
  command = argv[1];
else cout<<"Not enough commands"<<endl;
```

Comment: Would this be a correct way to allocate it                                                          node* temp;
        temp = new node;

Comment: Yes, it is right. But I think you really need to check [this site](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/) to learn more about dynamic memory @Matteo

Comment: I read the site and then I ran the debugger but I stil on't understand why it gives that the error is temp->name="Free"

Comment: Because temp points to NULL, which stands for nothing at all. When you ask something such as the string "Free" from nothing, the program will crash.@Matteo